# Run-time error '3001': Invalid Argument when creating a table in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

When creating a table in Access VBA using the following code:

```
Set tbl = dbs.CreateTableDef("" & strTableName & "")
```

I get the following error: `Run-time error '3001': Invalid Argument`. What causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the table you're trying to create (in the above example expressed as `strTableName`) is not valid - it's probably either null or too long.

The names of Access 2010 tables can be no longer than 64 characters. If strTableName is not null and has fewer than 64 characters, the above code will work perfectly.

Comment: Or strTableName could be Null

Comment: @4dmonster - Yes, good point - in short, anything that creates an invalid table name would generate this error.